# Uniform convergence of a seriesobtained by dominating it with another series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of complex valued functions on the real line and $n$ be integers. If there is a sequence of nonnegative numbers $\{a_n\}$ such that $\sum _{n} \mid  f_n(x) \mid \leq \sum_{n} a_n < \infty$ for all $x$ in the domain, then can I conclude that $\sum_{n} f_n$ converges uniformly on the domain? If so, how do I prove it? I first tried the Weierstrass test but it does not seem to fit in this situation. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: I suppose that you forgot to add that $\sum_na_n$ converges.

Comment: Oh I forgot. Yes it must converges. Then could you explain how to prove the question?

Comment: No, but I'll think about it.

Comment: You can't. Take $f_n=\chi_{[n,n+1)}$, $a_1=1$, and $a_n=0$ for $n>1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your conjecture is wrong in general:
consider $f_n: [0,1] \to \mathbb R: x \mapsto x^n \cdot (1-x)$.

Then for $x\neq 1$, $\sum_n \vert f_n(x) \vert = 1 = \sum_n \frac1{2^n}<\infty$ (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76104/does-absolute-convergence-of-a-sum-imply-uniform-convergence)), but $\sum_n \vert f_n(1) \vert=0$. Thus the pointwise limit is not continuous and thus the convergence is not uniform since each $f_n$ is continuous.

Comment: OK, I forgot to add that the inequality also holds for every subset of $\mathbb{Z}$... Then I think what I claim is true.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_n f_n(x)$ is uniformly Cauchy since $\sum_{k=n}^m |f_k(x)| \leq \sum_{k=n}^m a_n \to 0$ as $m,n \to \infty$

Hence $\sum_n f_n(x)$ converges uniformly.

Comment: Something is wrong here, since my sequence also seems to be uniformly Cauchy